# Extract unique coefficient estimates from glm

Tags: r, glm, lme4

I have 57 individuals (with ~60,000 replicates) labeled by "ID_Year" used to create a GLME model of habitat selection.  How do I extract unique coefficient estimates for each "ID_Year"?

Here is the model:

```
Cand.mod[[25]] <-glmer(Used ~ WBEMesicHa + Treatments + WBERoads45 + WBERoads25 + WBERoadsUn + Powerlines + Agricultur + UrbanEucli+ NonUrbanEu + ClippedCan + (1|ID_Year),family=binomial(logit),data=data)#failed to converge
```

I have tried `fixef(Cand.mod[[25]])` and get a single output of the model estimates:

```
 (Intercept)   WBEMesicHa   Treatments   WBERoads45   WBERoads25   WBERoadsUn   Powerlines   Agricultur   UrbanEucli   NonUrbanEu  ClippedCan2  ClippedCan3 
-4.195335406  0.045302307 -0.111918732 -0.036906751  0.025336140  0.240330206  0.209806088  0.073736439 -0.004829703 -0.217925175 -1.070915726 -1.866897616 
 ClippedCan4  ClippedCan5 
-2.833117637 -5.124756532
```

But I just can't get it for each of the 57 individuals.  I'm sure I'm missing something simple...

Comment: @Roland I had tried that earlier, and while it does return estimates for all 57 individuals, the only coefficient that changes by individual is the intercept.  The other coefficients remain static...

Comment: Yes, of course. After all, you only have a random intercept. The slopes must be the same for all individuals. If you want random slopes, you need to specify that. (I noticed the comment regarding convergence failure. You should investigate that.)

Comment: @Roland I meant to delete that comment at the end.  I investigated it with Ben Bolker's suggestions - it appears to be a non-issue for now.  How do I specify random slopes?

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/13173/11849

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more like what I was looking for:

http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/lme4/docs/isREML